# OBIEE12C: NULL appearing as option in dashboard prompt choice list

Tags: obiee

I have a dashboard prompt with various fields to allow the client to filter the data by year, quarter, month.

I have my own development environment and when I test the prompt in my OBI server everything looks fine. But when I deploy the prompt in the client environment something weird happens: the NULL value appears as an option in the choice list.

Any clue about why could this happen?

Comment: what kind of dashboard prompt is it ? if its column prompt you should check your tables records , most probably reason is you have some null values there  OR you shopuld check your obiee Admin part to see what is your data types for these column...

Comment: Thank you for your response Ali. It is a Column prompt based on a calculated field. This field is calculated by extracting the YEAR from a timestamp field. Although this timestamp field is nullable, I have checked in the database and there is no record where this timestamp field appears with NULL value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prompt is populated by a query. That query accesses the database. If your query returns a NULL and the query is the same in both environments that means that your database is the place where there's a difference.

a) Grab the two queries from both environments
b) Run both queries against their REPSECTIVE databases
c) Compare the results
d) Run both queries against the OTHER database
e) Compare the results

If the doesn't show you where the error source is, then your prompts are different and you made the error while configuring things in the front-end or the RPD and they are not as you say identical.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks a lot for your help! That's the weird thing: the database is the same. Both my environment and the client's access the same database. I know the prompts are identical because I did archive-unarchive to move it from one environment to the other

Comment: I have found what the problem is. The prompt showing the NULL values is a Column prompt based on a calculated field. This field is calculated by extracting the YEAR from a timestamp field. Looking into the RPD I saw that it uses the EVALUATE function. If I change it and use the EXTRACT YEAR function instead, the NULL value dissapears. What I cannot understand yet is why this happens in the client environment and not in my own environment. The only difference between both is that the OBI server in the client environment is Unix and my OBI is installed in a Windows server.

Comment: EVALUATE sends the code uninterpreted to the data source underneath and there is no logic happening in the BI server. That means that 100% of the logic and interpretation happens in the source. In your case the database. So if the two databases are configured / parametrized just a bit differently you will get different results.